# SQLPlus: using special character for password in script

Tags: sqlplus

I have issue with special character in password - '@'.
Issue that i don't know how to pass password with this special character to script file and connect using sqlplus.

For example i have user 'test_user' with password 'temp123@'. For login via sqlplus i use following string with escaping: `sqlplus test_user/\"temp123@\"@some-db:1521/SID`

It's works well. For my case i need to pass password as parameter for sql script. For example, i have following script to connect (actually script using several pairs of login/password to update many users at once):

```
-- @deploy.sql
connect &&2./&&3.@&&1.
```

At have failure with that because password with '@' can't interpreted correctly by sqlplus. I tried many advices from google with escaping but mostly of them applicable for connect string at sqlplus invoke. For my case its required for parameter that passed to script.

Answer (score 5):

> use : cmd.exe and not powershell window

```
if not :
```

> in powershell windows : sqlplus 'login/\"P@$$w0rd\"@TNS_NAME'
>
> in cmde.exe : sqlplus login/\"P@$$w0rd\"@TNS_NAME

Answer (score 0):

Just quotes required in connect string:

```
connect &&2./"&&3."@&&1.
```